# Meteor, MongoDB Manual Reference - 2 matching collection fields

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to determine if two collections have a field that match. My collections look like this:

```
Collection1.find().fetch();

_id: 'W6YB9M7FtKRdJHxgr',
postId: '1052732379946708491_1086374506',
voters: [ [Object] ],
totalVotes: 0

Collection2.find().fetch();

{
  {
  _id: 'ZEht9cYHemQ32Pkk7',
  postId: '1052732379946708491_1086374506',
  firstName: 'Frank',
  lastName: 'User'
  },
  {
  _id: 'KQpt8rYHemQ328aB',
  postId: '1052770843237994691_1864563700',
  firstName: 'Joe',
  lastName: 'UserTwo'
  }
}
```

I'm trying to check if collection1.postId equals some document in collection2.postId to decide which documents to perform actions on.

```
var a = collection1.findOne({},{postId: 1});
var b = collection2.findOne({postId: a});
```

Isn't returning collections where the fields match. The idea would be that I could then say:

```
if(b) {
  collection2.update({...});
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I need you to be more specific about the preconditions. Which of these are true: (1) You know exactly which field you wish to compare, (2) You know exactly which value of that field you wish to compare.

Comment: @DavidWeldon I know exactly which field I want to compare, but not necessarily whether the value of that field matches.

Answer (score 0):

You're not specifying the fields subset correctly on the one hand and on the other hand even if you specify only one field you'll automatically get the *_id* as well in the return *object*. Try:

```
var a = collection1.findOne({},{fields: {postId: 1}}).postId; // a will now be a string instead of an object
var b = collection2.findOne({postId: a});
```